# Error with homebrew + opencv + libpng

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, libpng

On Mac OS Maverick I have installed OpenCV with a `brew install opencv`.

I created a simple program (copied from [this tutorial](http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/)). Compilation worked fine but when running the executable I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib requires version 33.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 32.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I checked that `libpng`was properly installed via `brew install libpng` and ran a `brew upgrade` to make sure everything was up-to-date.

Running `locate libpng16.dylib` returns:

```
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.10/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.12/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.13/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.15/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homebrew should ensure that you the correct dependencies install. However, it's possible that you have more than one version of `libpng16` installed at different paths. Have a look in...

```
/usr/lib
/opt/local/lib
```

If you find any versions of the library in these locations then they may be causing the wrong one to be loaded when your program starts.  As a quick fix you can try typing `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` before your program name on the command line. In the longer term you may need to remove the conflicting versions altogether.

Comment: There are several versions of `libpng16` in my `/usr/local/Cellar/libpng` folder (but none in `/usr/lib` or `/opt/local/lib`). And the one in `/usr/locale/lib` (which is obviously loaded by dylib) is a symlink to the latest version in `/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.16`). So it looks correct to me, isn't it?

Comment: If there are no other version elsewhere then it doesn't look like a version conflict. It seems that you need a newer version of `libpng`. I'd have thought that Homebrew would've installed the correct dependencies though

Comment: You're right. I've just downloaded, built and installed the latest version of `libpng` and it works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: Just had the same update `brew update && brew upgrade libpng` worked for me. Upgraded from `libpng.1.6.15` to `libpng.1.6.16` my issue was opencv related as well.

Comment: Remove brew's libpng, and download source and compile did work

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is to fully uninstall libpng and re-install it:

```
$ sudo brew uninstall libpng
$ sudo rm '/usr/local/bin/libpng-config'
$ for i in `brew link --overwrite --dry-run libpng`; do sudo rm $i; done
$ sudo brew install libpng
```

If you need to install opencv:

```
$ sudo brew tap homebrew/science
$ sudo brew install opencv
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for OSX users who installed through Conda, more specifically the conda-forge channel (I'm not sure about others).

Conda ends up installing its own libpng in the environment and you can update it with `conda upgrade libpng`.

I guess this is basically a bug with the opencv recipe on conda-forge.