# Python: Error importing OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, homebrew

I installed opencv with Homebrew. I'm getting the following error -

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.11_1/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib requires version 34.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 33.0.0
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124359/error-with-homebrew-opencv-libpng

Answer (score 0):

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
```

^ libpng hasn't been loaded for some reason

```
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.11_1/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
```

^ highgui tried to load it.

```
Reason: Incompatible library version
```

^ `libopencv_highgui` looks to require at least version 34.0.0 of `libpng`, whereas you have version 33.0.0. I expect updating libpng should do the trick.